# Mix webcam video, audio with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, webcam, webcam-capture

How to mix h264 format with audio on webcam with gstreamer?

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-h264,framerate=30/1,width=1920,height=1080 \
! queue ! mux. \
alsasrc device=hw:1 ! queue ! audioconvert ! fdkaacenc \
! mux. matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=video.mkv 

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstAudioSrcClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
../libs/gst/base/gstbasesrc.c(3127): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.001309727
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Preview works

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! video/x-h264,framerate=30/1,width=1920,height=1080 ! decodebin ! autovideosink
```

Audio works

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v alsasrc device=hw:1 ! queue ! audioconvert ! fdkaacenc ! fdkaacdec ! autoaudiosink
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

h264parse needed before mux

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v \
v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! queue ! video/x-h264,framerate=30/1,width=1920,height=1080 \
! h264parse ! mux. \
alsasrc device=hw:1 ! queue ! audioconvert ! fdkaacenc ! mux. \
matroskamux name=mux ! filesink location=video.mp4
```